# Links in bio not clickable in Android app

Tags: bug, android-app

Go to a user page in the Android app. Clicking on their website opens a browser. However, any links that had been inside their bio text are not clickable. They are just plain text. Would be nice if they would be clickable as well.

Answer (score 1):

As of v1.0.82 (beta)<sup>or somewhere before that</sup>, it has been fixed: the links inside *About me* are shown properly as links (not plain text), and clickable:

- Tapping a link to a post on SE will open the post inside the app
- Tapping a tag will perform a tag search on current site inside the app
- Tapping an external link will open it in in-app browser or external browser

[image: user profile's about us as of 1.0.82]